# Resources for Japanese should include on line radio

Tags: feature-request

We have had a couple of requests for radio stations available ("streamed") on line by people looking something they can listen to as background while they work. Perhaps we should add a new section to "Resources for learning Japanese"  to cater for this demand?

Answer (score 3):

On the one hand, given the small number of podcasts, we could potentially rename that "podcasts/streaming audio".

On the other hand, I'd like to be a bit cautious about adding generic "native Japanese practice material". We've sortof made an exception for children's books, but that's mostly because the level of Japanese learner interested in that material is going to have difficulty searching the web for it. I don't think that's the case with radio.

Googling for 日本語ラジオ (in various permutations) brought me to a series of streaming sites. There were some false-positives, but it only took a few minutes to find what I was looking for. Note that, relative to the US, few Japanese radio stations bother to go through the hoops needed to broadcast music, but perhaps places like http://lastfm.jp are better for that anyway.

On the other hand, we also have alot of "gutenberg-in-japanese"-type links up there. So perhaps we're just being suspicious of this whole 'new media' thing on our webpage thingamajig.

(and no, I've flipped sides so many times in this that I have no idea what an 'upvote' for this answer means anymore)

Comment: (1) I was not really thinking about podcasts, just old fashioned radio. (2) I don't have a strong feeling about this but my purpose was to stop such requests appearing on the main website....altho it might not make any difference to the number of requests we can redirect them a little more pleasantly.